# Area of square with integer co-ordinates

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, number-theory, coordinate-systems

What is property of the integers $x$, such that there a lattice square (square with integer co-ordinates) of area $x$ ?

I'm stumped by this question. a complete explanation would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Take the short [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how how to get the most from your time here. For typesetting equations please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

If we place one vertex at $(x_1,y_1)$ and a second vertex at $(x_2,y_2)$, we generate a side of length $(\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$ from which a square can be constructed with area $(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2$. So any area which is the sum of two square integers (one of which might be $0$) can be obtained.